# How to correctly reset an incremented counter?

Tags: winforms, powershell, counter, reset

In one of my scripts I'm using a counter which I gradually increment if a specific event happens. I use the following syntax to do so:

```
if ($IndexPositionTrue) {
    $CorrectTextbox.Text = $script:countercorrect++
}
```

Right now I'm trying to implement a button with which you can reset the `$countercorrect` value back to 0. For this I setup a button with a click_handler:

```
$reset = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$reset.Add_Click($handler_reset_click)
$form1.Controls.Add($Reset)

$handler_reset_click = {
    Reset
}

function Reset {
    Clear-Variable countercorrect
}
```

Let's say the `$countercorrect` value has been incremented to 5 and I use the `Reset` function. The value does get reset to 0 but after the next increment instead of displaying 1 it displays 6.

Is my syntax incorrect or am I "resetting" the wrong value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a scope issue ,can you modify the reset function like this:

```
function Reset {
    $script:countercorrect = 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't even think about -Scope.

Comment: Instead of clearing the variable (after which it has the "value" `$null`) you should probably reset it to zero: `$script:countercorrect = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You refer `$Script:countercorrect` in your If-Statement but refer to `$countercorrect` in your function `reset`. If think you are using the wrong scope here.

Use the function

```
function Reset {
Clear-Variable countercorrect -Scope Script
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This was exactly the problem here. :)